# checking sessions cookie asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which checks if there is a cookie session via an ajax call before the user adds of edits data
the problem is that it takes too long to make the call to return the value in time so instead it always returns: undefined
is there a way to run this function so that it will return the data in time? thanks for reading.

```
function checkSession(){
  $.get('/check_session.php',function(data){
      if(data == "loggedOut"){
         return "lo";
  }
}

function doSomething(){ //check if your logged in
   if(checkSession() == "lo"){ //always returns:undefined
      alert('your have been logged out');
   }else{ //do stuff

 }
}
```

Comment: simply check the cookie in JS, not PHP; they expire on both sides...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.It's not a problem with the server's response time. You have placed the `return` statement under the callback function that will be called asynchronously when `$.get` is done, so basically `checkSession()` will never return your expected value.

2.You have some options to resolve your problem: use `$.deferred` or turn your ajax method into a synchronous call. I personally choose the second one.

```
function checkSession(){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: YOUR_URL,
        async: false
    }).responseText == "loggedOut" ? "lo" : "something";
}
```